# Image is not showing up in Whatsapp link

Tags: html, image, whatsapp, meta

I want to display the image when I paste the link of webpage to whatsapp. But somehow it's not showing up there. I've been able to show the description but image is not showing till yet. I have tried all the snippets on so but couldn't be succeeded somehow. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta name="description" content="description of my website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="title of my page heading" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/example.php" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="desc">

    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="http://urlOfmyimage.jpg">
   <meta itemprop="width" content="256">
    <meta itemprop="height" content="256">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to your question, I did some research and solved it.

you need an image less than 50 or 100 kb.

```
<meta  property="og:type" content="...">
<meta  property="og:url" content="...">
<meta  property="og:title" content="...">
<meta  property="og:image" content="...jpg">
<meta  property="og:description" content="...">
<meta  property="og:site_name" content="...">
```